# bluez rfcomm connect fail

Tags: linux, bluetooth, embedded, rfcomm

I am trying connect Ubuntu pc with device. While command entered, it returns various error including **rfcomm connect address already in use** 、 **host is down** 、 **rfcomm connect now in progress**.

Device environment and procedure as below

Device environment

- Linux 3.4
- Bluez 5.19
- bt addr xx:xx:xx:xx:38:A4

PC environment

- Ubuntu 14.04
- bluez 4
- bt addr xx:xx:xx:xx:CF:F0

steps

**device**

- insmod rfcomm.ko  rtk_btusb.ko
- dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/dbus-1/system.conf
- bluetoothd -C &
- hciconfig hci0 up
- hciconfig hci0 piscan
- sdptool add SP
- bluetoothctl scan on
- bluetoothctl agent on
- bluetoothctl default-agent
- bluetoothctl trust xx:xx:xx:xx:CF:F0
- bluetoothctl pair xx:xx:xx:xx:CF:F0
- rfcomm bind 0 xx:xx:xx:xx:CF:F0 1
- chmod 666 /dev/rfcomm0
- rfcomm connect 0 xx:xx:xx:xx:CF:F0 1

**PC**

- sdptool add SP
- rfcomm bind 0 xx:xx:xx:xx:38:A4 1
- chmod 666 /dev/rfcomm0
- rfcomm watch 0 1

Device show *Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down*

hciconfig -a output

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 5C:F3:70:1B:38:A4  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN
        RX bytes:6888 acl:88 sco:0 events:230 errors:0
        TX bytes:4341 acl:84 sco:0 commands:87 errors:0
        Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
        Name: 'BlueZ 5.19'
        Class: 0x000000
        Service Classes: Unspecified
        Device Class: Miscellaneous,
        HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0xe2f
        LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x9f73
        Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)
```

Is any step missed in my procedure?

Comment: l2ping from PC to device work, but from device to PC show connection reset by peer after send 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

below steps works for me.

**PC side**

- sdptool add SP
- rfcomm -i hci0 watch 0 1 ./picocom /dev/rfcomm0

**Device side**

- sdptool add SP
- rfcomm connect 0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:F0 1 &
- picocom /dev/rfcomm0

[reference](http://chaoyunotebook.blogspot.tw/2015/10/ubuntu-raspberry-pi-serial-port.html)